# I cant align FloatLayout in center in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Iam tried align floatlayout in center, help-me?
Uploaded image for understanding...
My idea is recreate layout Windows 8 retro in Kivy, after add icons windows 8 retro in button.

[image]

My kv file:

```
<SMAgro>:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'center'
        FloatLayout:
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgb: [1,1,1,1]
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            Button:
                background_color: [.4,1,.1,1]
                pos_hint: {'x': 0.26, 'y': 0.328571}
                size_hint: 0.45, 0.3
                text: "Equipamentos"
#                StackLayout:
#                    pos: self.parent.pos
#                    size: self.parent.size
#                    orientation: 'lr-tb'
#                    Image:
#                        source: 'kivy.png'
#                        size_hint_x: None
#                        width: 74
#                    Label:
#                        size_hint_x: None
#                        width: 100
#                        text: "Equipamentos"

            Button:
                background_color: [.4,1,.1,1]
                pos_hint: {'x': 0.26, 'y': 0.15}
                size_hint: 0.225, 0.18
                text: 'Configuracoes'
            Button:
                background_color: [.4,1,.1,1]
                pos_hint: {'x': 0.486, 'y': 0.15}
                size_hint: 0.225, 0.18
                text: 'Sobre'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set FloatLayout size and add `pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.5, 'center_x': 0.5}`, so for example: your widest button has size_hint_x = 0.45 and buttons have size_hint_y = 0.18 + 0.3.

Size of container: `size_hint: 0.45, 0.48`

Now, if button has `size_hint: 1, 1`, it's 100% width and height of parent container(FloatLayout) and it's equal to 45% width and 48% height of window.

This code shows centered FloatLayout

```
FloatLayout:
    pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.5, 'center_x': 0.5}
    size_hint: 0.45, 0.48
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: [1,1,1,1]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Button:
        background_color: [.4,1,.1,1]
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': 0.375}
        size_hint: 1, 0.625
        text: "Equipamentos"
    Button:
        background_color: [.4,1,.1,1]
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': 0}
        size_hint: .5, 0.375
        text: 'Configuracoes'
    Button:
        background_color: [.4,1,.1,1]
        pos_hint: {'x': .5, 'y': 0}
        size_hint: .5, 0.375
        text: 'Sobre'
```

[centered FloatLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jN6Am.png)

Comment: Sorry for bad explanation, but my english is not very good. The main thing is that it's easier to center one thing(FloatLayout in this example) than center many things(3 buttons here)